# How to play NSData in AVPlayer?

Tags: objective-c, avplayer

I have downloaded video `NSData` from AWS server using cognate poolid. Trying to play `NSData` in `AVPlayer` after converting `NSData` to `NSURL`. But it is not playing.

In interface, I have defined

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVPlayer *avPlayer;
```

Here is the code

```
NSData *data = [UserProfileInfo getVideoData];
NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)data.length);

NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
_avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:dataString]];

_avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
AVPlayerLayer *videoLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:_avPlayer];
videoLayer.frame = videoPreviewView.bounds;
videoLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
[videoPreviewView.layer addSublayer:videoLayer];
[videoPreviewView.layer setOpacity:1.0];
[_avPlayer play];
```

Actually I am getting data here but when I am converting it into `NSString`

```
NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Then I am getting `nil` in **dataString**.
Please someone help.

Comment: add your UserProfileInfo data

Comment: UserProfileInfo is my Model class in which I have stored downloaded NSData. And I am getting NSData in data variable using method getVideoData.

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the NSDATA in your Document Directory and give its path to AVPlayer for playing it.

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *myPathDocs = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myVideo.mp4"];
            [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
            BOOL isFileWriteComplete = [yourNSdata writeToFile:myPathDocs atomically:YES];
    if(isFileWriteComplete)
    {
_avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myPathDocs]];
_avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
AVPlayerLayer *videoLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:_avPlayer];
videoLayer.frame = videoPreviewView.bounds;
videoLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
[videoPreviewView.layer addSublayer:videoLayer];
[videoPreviewView.layer setOpacity:1.0];
[_avPlayer play];
    }
```